# react-script causes TypeScript to try to find the wrong file to import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relayjs, relay

I use React and I also use Relay which generates some TypeScript files that my app includes and after changing the directory in which those files are generated, TypeScript is complaining it can't find them, but there's something odd.

For example, this is what the TypeScript compiler says:

```
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...

.\src\pages\MyAccount.tsx
Cannot find file './__generated__/MyAccountMutation.graphql' in '.\src\pages'.


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Which is true, there's no `/src/pages/__generated__/MyAccountMutation.graphql`, but `MyAccount.tsx` is not requiring that file. The import line is:

```
import {MyAccountMutation} from "../__generated__/MyAccountMutation.graphql"
```

which is correct, there's a `/src/pages/../__generated__/MyAccountMutation.graphql` (that is `/src/__generated__/MyAccountMutation.graphql`) present.

Running `tsc` works just fine. This problem also happens with React development server.

Any ideas why React/TypeScript would try to get the wrong file?

Answer (score 0):

when using react-scripts, you're probably also using the `babel-plugin-relay/macro`, correct? The macro needs to be configured with `--artifactDirectory` too, but that's not possible when using react-scripts. You have three options:

1. eject from react-scripts and configure the macro
2. use a 'configuration override' like CRACO to do it (I have no experience with this).
3. don't use the `--artifactDirectory` for the relay compiler.